# Xtext Validation split over multiple plugins

Tags: java, validation, dependency-injection, eclipse-plugin, xtext

I would like to have different validations active depending on the loaded plugins.

the `mylang.database` plugin should provide a warning like

```
    mylangElement {
       id = "helloWorld"  //Warning id should start with an upper case
    }
```

while the `mylang.server` the plugin should warn like

```
    mylangElement {
       id = "helloWorld"  //Warning id must not exceed 8 letters
    }
```

(and possibly have both if both plugins are present)

What is the recommended way to do that?

- the root `mylang` validator alters behavior if the plugins are present (yikes)
- use the basic eclipse validation extension points (slow?)
- write API so that plugins can register additional validations to the root `mylang` validator
- there is a way provided by `xtext` with the neat `@Check` annotations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you consider to simply hook into the validation mechanism xtext already uses. i assume you mean by "loaded" that the plugin that contains the validator is activated (thus the plugin activated)

then you could do something like this (in activator start)

```
MyValidator val = new MyValidator();
Injector injector = IResourceServiceProvider.Registry.INSTANCE.getResourceServiceProvider(URI.createURI("dummy.mydsl")).get(Injector.class);
injector.injectMembers(val);
```

with myvalidator

```
public class MyValidator extends AbstractDeclarativeValidator {

    public static final String INVALID_NAME = "invalidName";

    @Override
    protected List<EPackage> getEPackages() {
        return Collections.singletonList(MyDslPackage.eINSTANCE);
    }

    @Check
    public void checkGreeting(Greeting g) {
        if (!Character.isUpperCase(g.getName().charAt(0))) {
            warning("Name should start with a capital", MyDslPackage.Literals.GREETING__NAME, INVALID_NAME);
        }
    }

}
```

alternatively you could create a class like the following

```
public class MyValidator extends AbstractDeclarativeValidator {

    public static final String INVALID_NAME = "invalidName";

    @Override
    protected List<EPackage> getEPackages() {
        return Collections.singletonList(MyDslPackage.eINSTANCE);
    }

    @Check(CheckType.FAST)
    public void checkFast(EObject g) {
        // TODO
    }
    @Check(CheckType.NORMAL)
    public void checkNormal(EObject g) {
        // TODO
    }
    @Check(CheckType.EXPENSIVE)
    public void checkExpensive(EObject g) {
        // TODO
    }

}
```

bind it in MyDslRuntime or preferrable uimodule like

```
class MyDslUiModule extends AbstractMyDslUiModule {

    @SingletonBinding(eager=true) def Class<? extends MyValidator> bindMyValidator() {
        return MyValidator
    }
}
```

and fill the todos with your own mechanism (e.g. own extension point etc)